# Does $X_t = M_t+V_t$ have to hold everywhere in the definition of a semi-martingale?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, definition, martingales

I'm reading about *continuous semi-martingale* from page 8 of these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf).

---

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space.

**Definition.** A *continuous semi-martingale* w.r.t. a filtration $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$ is a process $(X_t, t\ge 0)$ that can be written as $X_t = M_t+V_t$ where

- $(M_t, t\ge 0)$ is a continuous square-integrable martingale w.r.t. $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$.
- $(V_t, t \ge 0)$ is a continuous process that has bounded variation and is adapted to $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$ such that $V_0 = 0$ a.s.

**Example 1.** Let $H$ and $K$ be continuous adapted processes such that $\mathbb E [\int_0^t H_s^2 \mathrm d s] <\ \infty$ for all $t\ge 0$. Then the process $X = (X_t, t\ge 0)$ defined as
$$
X_t := \underbrace{X_0 + \int_0^t H_s \mathrm d B_s}_{M_t} + \underbrace{\int_0^t K_s \mathrm d s}_{V_t} \quad \forall t\ge 0.
$$
is a continuous semi-martingale.

**Example 2.**  Let $(B_t, t \ge 0)$ be the standard Brownian motion and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ twice continuously differentiable such that $\mathbb E [\int_0^t (f'(B_s))^2 \mathrm d s ] < \infty$. By Itô's lemma,
$$
f(B_t) = \underbrace{f(B_0) + \int_0^t f'(B_s) \mathrm d B_s}_{M'_t} + \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(B_s) \mathrm d s}_{V'_t} \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \forall t \ge 0.
$$
Then $(f(B_t), t \ge 0)$ is a continuous semi-martingale.

---

In **Example 2**, $f(B_t) = M'_t+V'_t$ a.s. So for each $t \ge 0$, $f(B_t)$ and $M_t+V_t$ can differ on a $\mathbb P$-null set. I am **not** sure if there is $(M_t, V_t)$ with required properties such that $M_t (\omega) + V_t (\omega) = f(B_t) (\omega)$ for **all** $\omega \in \Omega$. The definition mentioned in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale?useskin=vector#Definition) Wikipedia page also uses **everywhere** inequality in the decomposition $X_t = M_t+V_t$, i.e., the phrase "a.s." does not appear.

> Could you elaborate on my confusion?

Comment: In stochastic calculus it has become so common to understand equalities in the $\mathbb P$-a.s. sense that it became a habit to drop that silently.

Comment: @KurtG. If the equality is understood in the $\mathbb P$-a.s. sense, then the *continuous semi-martingale* $(X_t, t\ge 0)$ are not necessarily adapted to $(\mathcal F_t, t\ge 0)$ and does not necessarily have continuous sample paths, right? If yes, this is surprising to me.

Comment: To fix such problems the completion of the filtration was introduced. Please google what the "usual conditions" are. Perhaps the blog almostsuremath.com by George Lowther drills down into this.